# Reading camera image using raspistill from C++ program

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I like to capture images using RPi at least 60Hz. My code is in C++ and we have a library [here](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam) for C++ interface. But that library has maximum 30Hz.
My target is minimum 60 Hz.
So far what I found is [raspistill](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspistill.md) can make upto 90Hz, so I am trying to interface my C++ program to raspistill code. 
I found one library here [PiCam](https://robotblogging.blogspot.sg/2013/10/an-efficient-and-simple-c-api-for.html#comment-form) that has direct interface to raspistll. Not very sure, it can go to 60Hz, I am still trying to test it and have a few issues.
My queries are

(1)How is it possible to have 60Hz fps at RPi using C++?

(2)To interface to PiCam, I have already compiled, build and installed the library with no issues.
But I get black image when I capture. What could be the issue? A part of my code is shown below.

```
CCamera* cam = StartCamera(640, 480,60,1,true);
    char mybuffer[640 * 480 * 4];
    int ret = cam->ReadFrame(0, mybuffer, sizeof(mybuffer));
    cout << " ret " << ret << endl;
    Mat img(480, 640, CV_8UC4,mybuffer);
    imwrite("img.jpg", img);
```

img.jpg is captured with black image.

(3)Using PiCam, how can I changed to Gray image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **Raspicam** from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/) on a Raspberry Pi 3 and get around 90 fps in black and white mode.

I am currently re-purposing the code for something else so it is not 100% perfect for your needs, but should get you going.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <raspicam/raspicam.h>
#include <unistd.h> // for usleep()

using namespace std;

#define NFRAMES 1000
#define WIDTH   1280
#define HEIGHT  960

int main ( int argc,char **argv ) {

    raspicam::RaspiCam Camera;
    // Allowable values: RASPICAM_FORMAT_GRAY,RASPICAM_FORMAT_RGB,RASPICAM_FORMAT_BGR,RASPICAM_FORMAT_YUV420
    Camera.setFormat(raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT_GRAY);

    // Allowable widths: 320, 640, 1280
    // Allowable heights: 240, 480, 960
    // setCaptureSize(width,height)
    Camera.setCaptureSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    // Open camera 
    cout<<"Opening Camera..."<<endl;
    if ( !Camera.open()) {cerr<<"Error opening camera"<<endl;return -1;}

    // Wait until camera stabilizes
    cout<<"Sleeping for 3 secs"<<endl;
    usleep(3000000);
    cout << "Grabbing " << NFRAMES << " frames" << endl;

    // Allocate memory for camera buffer
    unsigned long bytes=Camera.getImageBufferSize();
    cout << "Width: "  << Camera.getWidth() << endl;
    cout << "Height: " << Camera.getHeight() << endl;
    cout << "ImageBufferSize: " << bytes << endl;;
    unsigned char *data=new unsigned char[bytes];

    for(int frame=0;frame<NFRAMES;frame++){
       // Capture frame
       Camera.grab();

       // Extract the image
       Camera.retrieve (data,raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT_IGNORE);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

By the way, it works very nicely with [CImg](http://cimg.eu).

Also, I haven't yet had the time to see if it works faster to create a new thread to process each frame, or to have a few threads started at the beginning and use a condition variable to start one after acquiring each frame.

Comment: Yes currently I use that library and it has 30Hz frame rate maximum. Have you tested to have 90Hz fps? There is no configuration for setting fps. My image processing takes about 10ms, so if I read the image from a file, I can reach upto 100Hz. But I use that library for 640 x 480 frame size, I can have 30Hz maximum. So reading from camera is bottleneck for me. How can I set higher fps using that lbrary?

Comment: I can read 90+ fps. I do not set the rate, I just read the frames as fast as possible. Try reading 1,000 frames and measuring the time - then subtract 3 seconds stabilisation time. I got around 14 seconds.

Comment: Thanks I'll implement threading, splitting image reading thread and processing thread.

Answer (score 0):

What Mark Setchell responded is correct.

But I found out that setting frame rate parameter is not exposed at its API level and can't set frame rate. Default frame rate is 30 Hz.
Can change it at src/private/private_impl.cpp file. I set to 60Hz and now it works.